# Can you center the text in a Tkinter Listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have been searching all over the place for something like this, and I'm beginning to think it's not possible.

I was thinking of using whitespaces as padding between the text, however, this would only work with a monospaced font.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: `tk.Listbox(root, justify="center")`.....

Comment: Option `justify` work only when version >= 8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simply `justify='center'` option will do the trick:

```
tk.Listbox(window, justify="center").pack()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! How was I not able to find this, I guess I was searching for the wrong question haha.